# javascript replace random letters with underscore

Tags: javascript, replace, character

I want to write this google spreadsheet javascript code to replace random letters in a string.

I have created a code that does it but not randomly, plus it also replaces the spaces with an underscore (which is problematic).

The end result I'm interested in is to go from this (the sentences are in French btw.):

`'J’habite à New York.'`

to this:

`'_’h_b_t_ à _ew _or_.'`

Let's say that given a sentences, at least half of the number of letters must be replaced with an underscore.

Thank you for your help. (ps: i'm not a programmer)

The code I have so far:

```
var v =  [['J’habite à New York.', 'Sì', ], ['Je m’appelle John. !']]; 

for (var r in v){
  for (var c in v[r]){
    var d = v[r][c];
    var l = d.length; 

    var u = l; 
    while(u > 0){
    var res = d.replace(d[u-2], '_');
    d = res; 
    u = u - 2;
      }
    console.log(res);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why was this question downvoted, might I ask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this :)

```
var a = "Text i want to replace text from";
var splitted = a.split('');
var count = 0; // variable where i keep trace of how many _ i have inserted

while(count < a.length/2) {
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length); //generate new index
   if(splitted[index] !== '_' && splitted[index] !== ' ') {
       splitted[index] = '_';
       count++;
   } 
}

var newstring = splitted.join(""); //the new string with spaces replaced
```

EDIT: i tried it now on console and seems to be working. What problem does it give to you?

2° EDIT: you could do:

```
splitted[index] = ' _ ';
```

instead of

```
splitted[index] = '_';
```

also notice that i changed the if condition from:

```
if(splitted[index] !== '_')
```

to

```
if(splitted[index] !== '_' && splitted[index] !== ' ')
```

to avoid replacing empty spaces with '_'

:)

Comment: This seems like a good way to solve the "at least 50% replace" problem, i foxed some formattig, feel free to rollback.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please improve the last line since it doesn't seem to work. Thanks !

Comment: Now it works, thanks a lot. I know it's a further demand but how can I obtain a result that is going to render sth like "w_ _ t" instead of "w__t" ? (want). Each underscore corresponds to one letter and when you have two next to each other it's confusing.

Comment: Thanks Murys for your solution. It is simple and it works perfectly. I also want to avoid the punctuation marks (in French there are more than in English) so I have come up with a solution but I'm wondering if it couldn't be done in a more efficient and simpler way (and more exhaustive, i.e. including all the signs). Thanks. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/pnnaoned/4cc7d1a421430b2e795786dd0ebb7511

Answer (score 2):

You are overcomplicatig a bit. Just turn the string into an array of characters, then map it to an array of characters with some letters replaced and turn it back into a string.

```js
function replace(str) {
  return str.split("").map(char => Math.random() > 0.5 ? "_" : char).join("");
}


var v = [
  ['J’habite à New York.', 'Sì', ],
  ['Je m’appelle John. !', 'Non!',]
];


for (const pair of v) {
  pair[0] = replace(pair[0]);
  pair[1] = replace(pair[1]);
}

console.log(v)
```

Comment: This is what I was going to post, however, he mentions `at least half of the number of letters must be replaced with an underscore` which this doesn't always do.

Comment: @getOffMyLawn currently thinking about a good solution, haven't yet found one except "retry until it fits"

Comment: I was thinking count the number of underscores and if it is less than half replace some that aren't underscores

Comment: This one looks nice. However how to: 1: add a space between underscores 2: exclude punctuation marks ?